# ¿Cómo crear un JSON y recórrelo como si fuera una lista?

Tags: javascript, json

pues tengo este programa en el que creo un JSON, lo parseo y una vez hecho eso mediante un bucle creo la lista en la que debe ir para que se muestre por pantalla.
El problema es que no se si lo he creado bien y además a la hora de crearlo me da un fallo en el ***appendchild*** ya que debe esta guardado en un ***div*** que tiene un ***ul*** y  dentro del ***ul*** una lista.
Dicho todo esto aquí paso el código.

html:

```
<div>
    <div id="json"></div>
    <div>
```

javascript:

```
  /*
        Generar un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

        {
            {vehicle: coche, type: tierra},
            {vehicle: tanque, type: tierra},
            {vehicle: barco, type: mar},
            {vehicle: avioneta, type: aire},
            {vehicle: globo, type: aire},
            {vehicle: moto, type: tierra}

        }

        Mostrar el JSON generado en la capa
    */
   var json = {
       vehiculos:[
        {vehicle:" coche", type: "tierra"},
        {vehicle: "tanque", type: "tierra"},
        {vehicle: "barco", type: "mar"},
        {vehicle: "avioneta", type: "aire"},
        {vehicle: "globo", type: "aire"},
        {vehicle: "moto", type: "tierra"}
       ]
   }

   var data = JSON.stringify(json);
   console.log(data);

   var div1 = document.getElementById('json');

   for (let i = 0; i < data.vehiculos.length; i++) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var txt = document.createTextNode(data[i].vehicle+':'+data[i].type);
    console.log(data[i].vehicle)
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(txt);
    div1.appendChild(ul);
   }
```

Comment: Lo que llamas `json` es realmente un Objeto JavaScript. Al usar el método `stringify` lo conviertes en una cadena en formato JSON. Como podrás suponer, intentar acceder a la propiedad `vehiculos` de una cadena es incorrecto. El paso de usar `stringify` está demás. La confusión viene seguramente de pensar que JSON es lo mismo que Objeto, cuando no es así. JSON es un formato de texto, que al ser analizado (`parse`) por Javascript, es convertido en un objeto de JavaScript. Prueba tu código sin usar `stringify`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, Si tienes razon muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas.

Primero, la línea

```
var data = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Lo que hace es convertir un objeto a un `string`, por lo tanto data sería un `string` y eso no es lo que necesitas, necesitas iterar sobre el objeto (Variable llamada `json`) directamente

Segundo, esta línea entonces debes actualizarla para que haga uso del json y no de `data` (que es un string)

```
 for (let i = 0; i < data.vehiculos.length; i++) {
```

Tercero, en esta línea:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode(data[i].vehicle+':'+data[i].type);
```

`data` es un string, y además si quisieras acceder a los datos, deberías primero acceder al array de vehiculos, así:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode(json.vehiculos[i].vehicle+':'+json.vehiculos[i].type);
```

Extra: estas creando un nuevo `<ul>` en cada iteración, lo que deberías es crear un único `<ul>` y en la iteración crear los `<li>` .

Aqui te dejo el código todo junto.
Saludos

```js
/*
        Generar un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

        {
            {vehicle: coche, type: tierra},
            {vehicle: tanque, type: tierra},
            {vehicle: barco, type: mar},
            {vehicle: avioneta, type: aire},
            {vehicle: globo, type: aire},
            {vehicle: moto, type: tierra}

        }

        Mostrar el JSON generado en la capa
    */
var json = {
  vehiculos: [{
      vehicle: " coche",
      type: "tierra"
    },
    {
      vehicle: "tanque",
      type: "tierra"
    },
    {
      vehicle: "barco",
      type: "mar"
    },
    {
      vehicle: "avioneta",
      type: "aire"
    },
    {
      vehicle: "globo",
      type: "aire"
    },
    {
      vehicle: "moto",
      type: "tierra"
    }
  ]
}

var data = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(data);

var div1 = document.getElementById('json');

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
for (let i = 0; i < json.vehiculos.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var txt = document.createTextNode(json.vehiculos[i].vehicle + ':' + json.vehiculos[i].type);
    console.log(json.vehiculos[i].vehicle)
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(txt);
}

div1.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="json"></div>
```

Comment: Una confusión muy típica es llamar "objeto json" a un objeto en Javascript. JSON es un formato de texto, por lo tanto es un `string` y eso no tiene nada que ver con un Objeto de JavaScript. Mi sugerencia es que edites tu respuesta y cambies "objeto json" por "objeto" a secas. Saludos

Comment: Si, es que realmente solo me refería al nombre del objeto... que es `json` (asi llamó la variable el OP en su código), Aun así voy a agregar una aclaración para que no queden dudas, muchas gracias